# Can LSTM train for regression with different numbers of feature in each sample?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In my problem, each training and testing sample has different number of features. For example, the training sample is as following:

> There are four features in sample1: x1, x2, x3, x4, y1
>
> There are two features in sample2: x6, x3, y2
>
> There are three features in sample3: x8, x1, x5, y3

x is feature, y is target.
Can these samples train for the LSTM regression and make prediction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider following scenario: you have a (way to small) dataset of 6 sample sequences of lengths: `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` and you want to train your LSTM (or, more general, an RNN) with minibatch of size 3 (you feed 3 sequences at a time at every training step), that is, you have 2 batches per epoch.

Let's say that due to randomization, on step 1 batch ended up to be constructed from sequences of lengths `{2, 1, 5}`:

```
  batch 1                
----------
  2 | xx
  1 | x
  5 | xxxxx
```

and, the next batch of sequences of length `{6, 3, 4}`:

```
  batch 2               
----------
  6 | xxxxxx
  3 | xxx 
  4 | xxxx
```

What people would typically do, is *pad* sample sequences up to the *longest sequence in the minibatch* (not necessarily to the length of the longest sequence overall) and to concatenate sequences together, one on top of another, to get a nice matrix that can be fed into RNN. Let's say your features consist of real numbers and it is not unreasonable to pad with zeros:

```
  batch 1                
----------
  2 | xx000
  1 | x0000
  5 | xxxxx 

 (batch * length = 3 * 5)
 (sequence length 5)


  batch 2               
----------
  6 | xxxxxx
  3 | xxx000 
  4 | xxxx00

 (batch * length = 3 * 6)
 (sequence length 6)
```

This way, for the first batch your RNN will only run up to necessary number of steps (5) to save some compute. For the second batch it will have to go up to the longest one (6).

The padding value is chosen arbitrarily. It usually should not influence anything, unless you have bugs. Trying some bogus values, like `Inf` or `NaN` may help you during debugging and verification.

Importantly, when using padding like that, there are some other things to do for model to work correctly. If you are using backpropagation, you should exclude the results of the padding from both, output computation and gradient computation (deep learning frameworks will do that for you). If you are running a supervised model, labels should typically also be padded and padding should not be considered for the loss calculation. For example, you calculate cross-entropy for the entire batch (with padding). In order to calculate a correct loss, the bogus cross-entropy values that correspond to padding should be masked with zeros, then each sequence should be summed independently and divided by its real length. That is, averaging should be performed without taking padding into account (in my example this is guaranteed due to the neutrality of zero with respect to addition). Same rule applies to regression losses and metrics such as accuracy, MAE etc (that is, if you average together with padding your metrics will also be wrong).

To save even more compute, sometimes people construct batches such that sequences in batches have roughly the same length (or even exactly the same, if dataset allows). This may introduce some undesired effects though, as long and short sequences are never in the same batch.

To conclude, padding is a powerful tool and if you are attentive, it allows you to run RNNs very efficiently with batching and dynamic sequence length.

Comment: If the length {6, 3, 4} is 6 word vectors, 3 word vectors and 4 word vectors embedded by word2vec. For exmable, 6 is [2,3,3,2,5,3], 3 is [4,3,6] and 4 is [3,6,3,2], and a target sale amount y goes with {6, 3, 4} . I want to train LSTM using  {6, 3, 4} and the target y. How can I make the input?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly and values [2,3,3,2,5,3] are laid out in "time" dimension (that is, every value corresponds to a "timestep" of a recurrent net), then you just add enough zeros to shorter sequences: e.g. [4,3,6,0,0,0]. For targets (labels), if there is one label *per-timestep*, you just add enough zeros to match the length of a corresponding input. If labels are one *per sequence* (looks like it is your case), then you should not need to pad labels. For real example, check this [article](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your input_size for LSTM-layer should be maximal among all input_sizes. And spare cells you replace with nulls:

max(input_size) = 5

input array = [x1, x2, x3]

And you transform it this way:
[x1, x2, x3] -> [x1, x2, x3, 0, 0]

This approach is rather common and does not show any negative big influence on prediction accuracy.